# passing data between components with vue-router

Tags: vue.js

There a re quite a few question with kind of a similar title to mine, but that is where my problem lies. Let's take a very common case where i'm building a recipe book.
i'm looping over my recipes and creating a link to the `Recipe.vue` component:

```
<router-link v-for="recipe in recipes" :to="{path: `/recipe/${recipe.title}`">
     <a>{{recipe.id}}</a>
</router-link>
```

now from what i understand there are few solutions:
1. setting `props:true` and pass a prop:
`<router-link v-for="recipe in recipes" :to="{name: 'Recipe', params: {recipe}}">
       <a>{{recipe.title}}</a>
</router-link>`

2. set `Recipe` as child component and pass the data as a regur parent=>child data transfer
3. use Vuex and state management to then "withdraw" the data from the store in the `Recipe` component
4. pass id to the `Recipe` component and then when its `mounted()` execute an http request to get the data of the specific item.

I'm finding it hard to understand what is considered best practice here and what should i choose for my production env.

the voice inside me says that number 3 - state management is an overkill and #4 is an unnecessary api call since i already have the data i need.

Any advice on which method should i use in the basic case of: first component is a list of recipes and then navigate from it to a component with single purpose of displaying the recipe data?

Comment: I would say the /recipe/example-recipe page should be loading the recipe information itself, not having it passed from the recipe list page. Otherwise, and this is just one of several examples, what if a user bookmarked that recipe and went directly to the specific recipe page? So I guess #4 kind of, but not even passing the id - looking it up from the url.

Comment: i understand, the best solution will be another http request?  feels odd because i already have the data but i guess ,considering the issues you brought up that the best solution

Comment: Well you could check if data is passed, and if it is not then load it with an http request - It's just necessary to have an http request implemented in case they aren't coming from the list of recipes. If you wanted to pass the recipe when possible, as you noted you could use any of the methods 1-3. You probably wouldn't see a typical programmer set up Vuex just for this, but if you were planning on a more complicated app with users, comments, or just more complexity then Vuex would definitely be best. If it were just this simple app then I think the most common would be #2 but #1 is fine too